# mysql - Syntax error on trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to write the following trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_test_1 AFTER INSERT ON test FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE sID INT;
        DECLARE m INT;
        DECLARE a INT;
        DECLARE c INT;

        SET sID = NEW.s;
        SELECT MONTH(NOW()) INTO m;
        SELECT YEAR(NOW()) INTO a;

        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO c 
            FROM testt t 
            WHERE t.m = m AND t.a = a AND t.sID = sID;

        IF c = 0 THEN 
            INSERT INTO testt VALUES (m, a, sID, '', '');   
        END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

The error is:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at
line 15
```

The tables are quite simple:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    s INT
);

CREATE TABLE testt(
    m INT,
    a INT,
    sID INT,
    t VARCHAR(200),
    d VARCHAR(500)
);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss END IF; at the end:

```
IF c = 0 THEN INSERT INTO testt VALUES (m, a, sID, '', ''); 
END IF;
END $$
```

Comment: Thanks, I was worried about other aspects and missed this little error.

Comment: Must wait some time from the start of the question to accept any. I'll do it as soon as I can.